# Why is there a mod keyword in Rust?

Tags: module, rust

After reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html), I'm wondering why there is a `mod` keyword and `mod.rs`?

I assumed that the directory hierarchy can describe the module as well.

Answer (score 17):

There are a couple of reasons why modules must be explicitly declared:

- Modules can be public (`pub mod foo;`) or private (`mod foo;`).
- They can have attributes applied to them, attributes that couldn’t sit inside the file; there are two primary examples of that: `#[path = "x.rs"]` specifying a different path, and `#[cfg(…)]`, for conditional compilation, for cases where the module would fail to parse or have its macros expand.

Comment: I'd also like to add that Rust doesn't compile files just because they exist; there must be a module definition somewhere in the crate pulling it in.

Comment: @llogiq: the question is about that very point: why is it *not* done that way?

Comment: Ok, I may need to rephrase that: It makes sense not to blindly compile arbitrary `.rs` files, just because they're lying around. Why compile something you don't use?

Comment: @llogic: I disagree. There is practically always a direct correspondence between the .rs files in the tree and the modules; were it not for the conditional compilation attributes matter, there really would be no reason for `mod` items—it *could* be handled automatically. And frankly, I often feel it might have been better if we had done thus, though it would require slightly more careful handling of module attributes before parsing the rest of a file and might have *slightly* muddied the phases of the compiler. But there really is no fundamental reason why we couldn’t do without `mod` items.

Comment: @llogiq why have a `.rs` file lying around that shouldn't be compiled?

Comment: You could conditionally compile a module e.g. `#[cfg(feature = "foo")]` mod foo; which would only use `foo.rs` if the feature is active.

Answer (score 8):

While it can, it can also be overridden:

```
#[path = "somewhere/else"]
mod lol;
```