# Why do I need `use` statements in a submodule but not in main.rs?

Tags: rust

I don't understand `mod` or `use`; I suppose that `mod` will import files into the project and `use` will use them.

I have a project with this hierarchy:

```
.  
|-- Cargo.lock  
|-- Cargo.toml  
|-- src  
|  |-- display.rs  
|  |-- list.rs  
|  |-- main.rs  
|  |-- parser.rs  
|  |-- sort.rs
```

Why do I need `use` in *list.rs* and not in *main.rs*? I use the function `sorting()` and `print_files()` in *list.rs* like I use the function `parse()` and `listing()` in *main.rs*.

**main.rs**

```
mod parser;   // Ok
mod list;     // Ok
mod sort;     // Ok
mod display;  // Ok
// use parser;// The name `parser` is defined multiple times

fn main() {  
    parser::parse();
    list::listing();  
}
```

**list.rs**

```
//mod sort;    // file not found in module `sort`
//mod display; // file not found in module `display`
use sort;      // Ok
use display;   // Ok

pub fn listing() {
    parcours_elements();
    sort::sorting();
    display::print_files();
}

fn parcours_elements() {

}
```

**sort.rs**

```
pub fn sorting() {

}
```

**display.rs**

```
pub fn print_files() {

}
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Specifically, there's no mention of what `mod parser` corresponds to. Even better, don't include code that isn't relevant to reproducing the problem. You probably only need 2 (maybe 3) files to demonstrate.

Answer (score 7):

First things first, go back and re-read [`mod` and the Filesystem](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-01-mod-and-the-filesystem.html). Then read it *again*. For whatever reason, many people have trouble with the module system. A ton of good information is contained in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/).

> I suppose that `mod` will import files into the project and `use` will use them.

`mod foo` "attaches" some code to the crate hierarchy, relative to the current module.

`use bar` avoids needing to type out the full path to something in the crate hierarchy. The path `bar` starts *from the root of the crate*.

---

When you have `mod parser` in *main.rs*, you are saying

> go find the file *parser.rs*<sup>1</sup> and put all the code in that file in the hierarchy relative to the crate root<sup>2</sup>.

When you try to then add `use parser` in *main.rs*, you are saying

> go to the root of the hierarchy, find the module `parser`, and make it available here (at the crate root) as the name `parser`.

This already exists (because that's where the module is defined!), so you get an error.

When you have `use sort` is *list.rs*, you are saying

> go to the root of the hierarchy, find the module `sort`, and make it available here (inside the module `list`) as the name `sort`.

This works fine.

<sup>**1**</sup> Or *parser/mod.rs*.

<sup>**2**</sup> Because *main.rs* (or *lib.rs*) are the crate roots.

See also:

- [Why is there a mod keyword in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32814653/155423)
- [Split a module across several files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22596920/155423)
- [How to include module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26388861/155423)